# XTRF Home API, how to paginate customers

Tags: api, pagination, xtrf

I'm trying to make a grid of customers with help of XTRF Home API, and I have more than 10.000 customers in my XTRF account, so I'd like to paginate them. How can I specify limit/offset in Home API /customers/ call? Query parameters "limit" and "offset" are not working, although they work in some other requests, for example in Customer API. XTRF docs for this request don't mention any means of limiting/offsetting also:

https://xtrf-dev.amestotranslations.com/api/doc/users/pages/customers.html#GET_/customers/

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using browser instead of /customers call?
You have to create(or use default) view in xtrf:

https://xtrf-dev.amestotranslations.com/api/doc/users/pages/browser.html